# I am trying to figure out below javascript and what it does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out below script and what it does.

Any help is appropriated

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

Comment: Have you looked up the documention for it?

Comment: Hint: it's using jQuery.

Comment: Prints "Hello World!" to the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) when the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) finishes loaded using [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: thanks @vox thats what i thought but wasn't sure

Comment: You read the api documentation on what it does and were unsure what it does?

Comment: I am checking the documentation now and can see lots of similar examples. Thanks all

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So let's go over this piece by piece.

The `$` is usually a reference to jQuery (https://jquery.com/) which is a library of a lot of really useful JavaScript functions and things.

```
$(document)
```

This is what's known as a `jQuery selector`. Essentially it locates whatever you put into it, and wraps it in a `jQuery` object that lets you call various functions on it. In this case, it's wrapping the entire document.

```
$(document).ready
```

The `ready` function registers a `jQuery` event handler that will be triggered when the element (in this case the document, I'm not sure if it can be added to other elements) has completed loading. In this case, the callback function you pass into it will run as soon as the entire webpage has loaded and is ready to begin processing. If you don't do this, your JavaScript will execute immediately as it is parsed, which could cause problems if not all of your DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
});
```

This declares an [anonymous function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp) that is passed in as the first parameter to the `ready` function. The contents of the function will be run as soon as the document is ready (as soon as the `ready` event has been triggered).

```
console.log('Hello World!');
```

This will output the text `Hello World!` to the console. In the case of a browser, it will show up in the browser console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

So this code will print the text `Hello World!` to the browser console when the DOM, or web page, has finished loading and is ready to execute.

Comment: Most in-depth answer I've ever seen for a simple `console.log` when the DOM loads.

Answer (score 1):

**You can read an explanation [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).**

From that site:

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready". jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.